# How can I hide URL language information for default language only on main page (WordPress+Polylang)?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

WordPress and Polylang.
How can I hide URL language information for default language only on main page?
Example:

```
`site.com – (en hide, main page)`
`site.com/en/contacts – (en show)`
`site.com/en/news – (en show)`
`site.com/it/ – (it show)`
`site.com/it/contacts – (it show)`
`site.com/it/news – (it show)`
```